# Where can I find the Java features list

Tags: java, language-features

This may be super easy to solve but I can't find the correct "google search term" and I've got tons of pages and none with the answer I'm looking for.

Does anyone knows or has a list of the available features of java as a language?

For instance.

- Define classes:

  ```
  class Employee { 
  }
  ```
- Define attributes

  ```
  private String name;
  ```
- Methods:

  ```
  public void hello() {
  }
  ```
- Class methods

  ```
  public static void main(){}
  ```
- Generics

  ```
  private List<String>  = ....
  ```
- Statements
- Assignments
- Declarations
- Inner classes
- operators
- control flow
- etc.
- etc.
- etc.

I'm looking something more like a cheat-sheet than a full tutorial. I know most of these features, but sometimes I would like to have something at hand where I can look at and say: "Oh yes, this is the way ternary operator is used in java"

Comment: Doh!.. I found while asking my question that the google term I was looking for was "cheat-sheet" :) :) I'm leaving the question open just to provide easy rep points :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html).

Answer (score 3):

Check out this site:

http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/11cheatsheet/

**Hello, World.**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have to mention DZone's [core java](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/core-java) (because it is quite good and it is not on the first page of a 'java cheat sheet' search :) ).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/jcheat.html) MindProd compilation. It looks like exactly the kind of document you are looking for.

Comment: Yeap, acutally my problem is I have to filter between all these results to see which is better. For instance while this you sent is very good, it lacks some features ( it has it but in other page )  +1 for the finding